# Asking for my original job description 2 years after starting role

Tags: job-description

Recently there has been a confusion with my role (not going to go into detail as that is a different topic).

I believe there would be something related to this confusion within the original job advert when I applied for the job. I applied for the job just over 2 years ago and got the role a few weeks later.

I do not have a saved copy of the job description as  I had to apply through an online portal.

Is it acceptable to ask for a copy of the original job description 2 years after already starting the job? Would it be HR that I ask for a copy of this?

I understand that role and responsibilities will change over years/months, but the current confusion regarding my role would not have changed.

Comment: Many (most?) employment contracts don't describe specific duties in any binding sense. In most US states, unless you're in a union, there's probably no binding agreement at all which describes specific duties. The employer can ask you to do things, and you can either choose to do them or not. The employer can also fire you, or you can choose to quit. When push comes to shove, you will probably have a hard time making an argument based on a job description.

Answer (score 2):

Do ask for your job description and HR would be the best place to start, it should be a normal question for them. There is no need to mention that you haven't got a copy at home.

An original job description is a good place to start a conversation about your original duties and responsibilities. In my opinion it is the most objective piece of paper to talk about when there is confusion about your role.

Chances are you drifted away from the original description, but the then identified gap is where you can talk about. You can also point to the ambiguity in the original description where you think the confusion is about.

Good luck!

Comment: I will speak to HR and ask for my original job description, I'm not entirely sure how to approach any "Why?" questions I receive when asking for it as I don't want publicize my current intent.

Comment: @Dritz depending on country, it might affect your tax, what kinds of employment protection apply etc. Without a country tag, it is hard to know which excuse would sound feasible. Also, the bigger company, the less chance HR will even bother to ask why.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it acceptable to ask for a copy of the original job description 2
>   years after already starting the job?

In most cases that would be acceptable, but it may also be pointless. If there is confusion around the role, then work actively with your manager to get it clarified and communicated. If you don't like what your doing, than look for constructive ways to modify your role.

I just don't think that a piece of paper from 2 years ago will much useful in driving the discussion. How would you use it?  *"Oh wow, now that I see your original job description, we will immediately change your role!*" is not going to happen.

Don't focus on the past: put your effort into solving the problem in front of you.